# Autocomplete textbox - display only the name (not the ID)

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ashx

After checking existing conversations about this issue, i didn't find a good solution for the following: autocomplete TB when the source is ashx file, 
implementing by jquery, and i want to get specific person. How to get selected UNIQUE person (id) but display on autocompleteing only the NAME ?

(I mean to some kind of seperating ID & Name fields, and hide the id but "remeber" it when some name chosed)... ?

For now, i displaying a string contains name and id together and it looks ugly..

Is someone knows how can i implement it please?..

Comment: Try using this: https://ashfaqasp.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/using-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-asp-net-ashx-file/ and http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-UI-AutoComplete-TextBox-with-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: @AT-2016, it Doesn't give solution to "how to hide id from displaying"...